# Show the Local Notification in ios on click of button

Tags: ios

I  am trying to  show the local notification in IOS when i clicked on button in Table View. Actually, have one button on every cell in table view. whenever i click on any button , i want to show the local notification  with Index path Row in notification.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? Otherwise, its difficult to help

Comment: are you sure you want to post a `UILocalNotification` or rather a `UIAlertView`?

Comment: There's lots of tutorials how to show a local notification. There's lots of tutorials about how to add a button to views. There's lots of tutorials about how to detect a click on a button. Don't come here and expect people to spoon feed you information which can very very very easily be found out from google.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want to show UIAlertView? You can only "show" local notification if your app is in background and it's obviously not if you're tapping on it. In foreground the only thing you get is  application:didReceiveLocalNotification: getting called.

Comment: Asking abt how to show local notification on click evemt method

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "show local notification"? If you just want to show a little dialog - that's UIAlertView. The real local notification is a system event that shows when your app is not active and you can make it active by responding to that notification.